# Standards for iOS system notifications

Tags: ios, notifications

Are there any standards or regulations concerning iOS system notifications? For example, it should contain at least one active button. If yes, please, give references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no guidelines for system notifications. The only guideline regarding notifications from the App Store Review Guidelines is as follows.

> **4.5.4** Push Notifications must not be required for the app to function, and should not be used for advertising, promotions, or direct marketing purposes or to send sensitive personal or confidential information.

<sup>https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/</sup>